# My-sql one to many relation join get sum of left table column

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

When we have two tables with one to many relation how we can get the sum of left table column.

```
Ex:
Player (player_id,name)
Stats (player_id, game_id, score)

Player
1  Aaron Brooks
2  Beno Udrih
3  James harden

Stats
player_id  score year
1          5     2017
1          3     2017
2          4     2016

The result I need to get is (Player scores in 2017)
Player         Score
Aaron Brooks   8
Beno Udrih     0
James harden   0
```

One player have many stat records.
Then how can I get **all the players** list with his sum of total scores. (Even if stats not available for one player his score need to be 0)

> Got the correct query

```
select p.player_id,p.name,coalesce(sum(s.score),0)
from player p
left join stats s on p.player_id = s.player_id and s.year=2017
group by p.player_id,p.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply simple aggregation and use left join on stats table to get all the records from player table whether they have records associated in stats table or not

```
select p.player_id,p.name,coalesce(sum(s.score),0)
from player p
left join stats s on p.player_id = s.player_id
group by p.player_id,p.name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4289c6/2)

Edit for filter

Move your filter for stats table from `where` clause to `on` clause

```
select p.player_id,p.name,coalesce(sum(s.score),0)
from player p
left join stats s on p.player_id = s.player_id and s.year=2017
group by p.player_id,p.name
```

Applying filter on left table using `where` clause will convert from left join to inner join

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ed79/1)

Comment: Thank you @khalid,
But when I filter it with year, it doesn't work correctly. Have you any idea why?

select p.player_id,p.name,coalesce(sum(s.score),0)
from player p
left join stats s on p.player_id = s.player_id
WHERE s.year=2017
group by p.player_id,p.name

Comment: @Chythi Update your question how you are applying filter ? I suggest you to add filter after `on` like `and s.year = '2017'`

Comment: @Khalid, It works. Thank you great help!